# $\log x$ maps closed intervals to closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the function $$f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \Bbb{R} , x\mapsto \log x$$ Let $B$ be a closed interval contained in $(0,\infty)$. How to prove $f(B)$ is closed ?

My try: Since $f$ is continuous, it assumes all its intermediates values. So $f\Bigl([a,b]\Bigr)=[c,d]$ and $f\Bigl([g,\infty)\Bigr)=[h, \infty)$ where $a,g>0, b<\infty,c=f(a),d=f(b),h=f(g).$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, except that you used without mentioning it the fact that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Can you please explain your comment into a bit more? Is $f$ increasing ?

Comment: @LearningMathematics If your function was $f(x)=e^{-x}$ then $f[1,\infty ) =(0,\frac 1 e ]$ which is not closed. So IVP itself is not enough in your proof. Your function is increasing and that is why the proof works.

Comment: Also that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log x = \infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $1-e^{-x}$ is also increasing, and it is still a counterexample. So increasing is not the right requirement. In fact, it's not required at all, as for instance $\sin(x)$ sends all closed intervals to closed intervals.

Comment: @Arthur: so the conclusion is...?

Comment: @Arthur What I wanted to point out was that teh equation $f([g,\infty ))=[h,\infty )$ was immediate from the fact that $f$ is increasing, continuous and tends to $\infty $ as $x \to \infty $. One can get the same conclusion by showing that $f$ attains its minimum on $[g,\infty )$ and monotonicity can be avoided but the short argument given by OP suggests he used monotonicity implicitly.